# Why is socket.io-client's socket.on( ) getting fired up multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

So, for some reasons, socket.once() is being fired up multiple times, even though they are inside a useEffect();
I am 100% sure that I am not emitting them multiple times, on the server sde.
Some of these events get fired up multiple times, and sometimes even cause memory leaks.
Here's the code inside of my useEffect() function;

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.once('room-joined', (msg) => {
      setState({ ...state, roomID: msg.msg, roomJoined: true, room: msg.room, leader: false });
      console.log(msg.users);
      console.log(msg.msg);
    });

    socket.once('start-flip', (msg) => {
      gotFinalResults = false;
      gotResults = false;
      normalized = false;
      setState({ ...state, game: '/flip' })
    });
    socket.once('ask-choice-dice', () => {
      gotFinalResults = false;
      gotResults = false;
      normalized = false;

      setState({ ...state, game: '/dice' });

    });
    socket.once('round-result', (msg) => {
      rockChoice = 'rock';
      setState({ ...state, rockRoundResult: msg, rockChoice: 'rock' });
    });

    socket.once('race-finished', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      setState({ ...state, raceFinished: true, raceList: msg });
    });

    socket.once('message', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      setState({ ...state, chat: [...state.chat, { author: msg.username, msg: msg.msg }] });
    });
    socket.once('player-disconnected', (msg) => {
      setState({ ...state, room: msg.room, chat: [...state.chat, { author: null, msg: msg.msg }] });
    });
    socket.once('room-created', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg.msg);
      setState({ ...state, roomID: msg.msg, roomJoined: true, room: msg.room, leader: true });
    });
    socket.once('new-connection', (msg) => {

      setState({ ...state, room: msg.room, chat: [...state.chat, { author: null, msg: msg.msg }] });


    });

    socket.once('exit-lobby', (msg) => {
      setState({ roomID: '', roomJoined: false, joinRoomID: '', chat: [], chatBox: [], room: {}, game: '', leaderQuit: true, leader: false });
    });
    socket.once('start-race', () => {
      gotFinalResults = false;
      gotResults = false;
      normalized = false;
      setState({ ...state, game: '/race' });
    });
    socket.once('initialize-race', (msg) => {
      gotFinalResults = false;
      gotResults = false;
      normalized = false;
      setState({ ...state, game: '/race', raceText: msg.text, raceTimer: true, startTime: performance.now(), raceInitiated: true });

    });
    socket.once('normalize', () => {
      gotResults = false;
      gotFinalResults = false;
      setState({ ...state, game: '/', choice: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1, voluntarily: false, timer: { enabled: false }, leaderQuit: false, submitted: false, victory: false, defeat: false, winners: [], loosers: [], rockChoice: 'rock', rockRoundResult: false, rockGameResult: false, raceChoice: '', startTime: null, raceSpeed: 0, raceTimer: false, raceFinished: null, raceList: [], raceInitiated: false, flipChoice: 'heads' });
    });

    socket.once('defeat', () => {
      gotFinalResults = true;
      console.log('oh no!')
      setState({ ...state, defeat: true });
    });
    socket.once('results', (msg) => {
      setState({ ...state, winners: msg.winners, loosers: msg.loosers });

    })
    socket.once('victory', () => {
      gotFinalResults = true;
      setState({ ...state, victory: true });
      console.log('oh yes!')
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all but one of the `.once` calls should make the problem pretty obvious:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.once('room-joined', (msg) => {
        setState({ ...state, roomID: msg.msg, roomJoined: true, room: msg.room, leader: false });
        console.log(msg.users);
        console.log(msg.msg);
    });
    // lots of other code
});
```

Since there is no dependency array, this effect callback is re-running every time the component re-renders. First time it renders, there will be one listener attached to a given event. Second time it renders, there will be two listeners attached to a given event. Etc.

Use an empty dependency array to ensure `.once` is only called once for each type.

You'll also need to use the callback form of the state setter in order to properly update it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.once('room-joined', (msg) => {
        setState(state => ({ ...state, roomID: msg.msg, roomJoined: true, room: msg.room, leader: false }));
        console.log(msg.users);
        console.log(msg.msg);
    });
    // lots of other code
}, []);
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but apparently, I am not able to access the current value of state inside useEffect(). Can you tell me if there's a way to access it?

Comment: Use the callback form instead for the state setter.

Comment: I know that it makes me sound a bit like a dummy, but can you please emphasize? What do you mean by callback form? Do you mean the useCallback hook?

Comment: Look at the answer. The state setter - `setState` - uses a callback instead of just passing a value. `setState(state => ({ ...state,` etc. Use that whenever you need the most up-to-date value when constructing the new state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, pal. I got it.